# Simple BI tools for business user to do slice and dice analysis on top of Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Suppose I want to migrate some tables from RDBMS datawarehouse into Cassandra platform where those table are de-normalized first, the question is , Is there a simple tools that can be used for business user to do slice and dicing analysis againts the Cassandra table ? e.g. via Excel Pivot table / Power Query ?

Really appreciate for any hints..

Thanks,
Octoni

Comment: Cassandra is a different kind of beast, better you learn the internals of how Cassandra works before doing this. Tableu+Spark+Cassandra works for your scenario, I'm not a BI guy, not sure about slice and dice but Tableu works.

Comment: Hi Sreekar, 

Thanks for responding my questions.  I already setup a cluster of some nodes of Cassandra and have tried to upload a text file to a Cassandra table.
I've tried to run some simple cql query and stuff as well and it's pretty  fast though. However the next challange is how to server this data to casual end-user who dont have knowledge in SQL. That is why I need to find a BI tool for them. Do you mean by using Spark SQL ? and is it like making a star schema metadata model in Spark on top of Cassandra, so the behaviour will be like ROLAP ?
please englighten me   :) Thanks  a lot

Comment: Tableu uses Spark connector and Spark APIs (Spark SQL is part of it). Spark inturn uses Cassandra as it's data source. That's how it work as far as I know.  This article might give a better idea. http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tableau-spark-cassandra